# Does a large static array corrupt the stack?

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow

I have some code as follows:

```
typedef struct _X
{
  int array[1000];
}X;

static X x;

int main()
{
   x.array[0] =100;

}
```

My question is, in main(), when x is referenced, does it consume 4*1000 bytes on the stack? In case of threads with limited stack size can it smash the stack ?

Comment: As `x` is declared global the number of threads does not matter, as every thread uses the same "instance" of `x`. To have every thread use its own "instance" of `x` it needs to be declared *thread local*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x does not occupy memory in the stack. It has static storage duration (and internal linkage) and is allocated in the static memory.

This statement

```
x.array[0] =100;
```

does not deal with the stack memory.

Comment: I guess you should explain the terms "storage duration" and "linkage".

Comment: @Kay They are other questions.:) Anybody can ask a corresponding question if he is interesting what they mean.

Comment: So is there any difference performance wise/otherwise with the above code and mallocing a pointer, and using it. ( x->array[0] =100)

Comment: @jogabonito It is obvious that allocating dynamically memory requires more time them allocating it statically.

Answer (score 3):

Your `x` is a static array so it is stored in the data segment, occupying the memory for 4000 ints. No stack is used.

Answer (score 3):

As you have already declared `x` as static, the memory will not be allocated on stack. It will be stored in **Uninitialized data segment**.

For more info: [Memory management in C](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/teoX.pdf)

Comment: It goes to the .bss, not .data.

Comment: @bss AFAIK bss is a data segment.

Comment: ELF, PE and probably most other formats divide between initialized and uninitialized data segments. As the referenced documents tells, too. `.data` is for initialized data, `.bss` is for "uninitialized data" (i.e. data that will be zeroed out at dynamic link time).

Comment: @Kay: Correct me if I'm wrong, static members are initialized to zero by default.

Comment: 1336087, yes, they are initialized with zero. But they go to the uninitialized data segment (.bss). "Uninitialized" data gets initialized at the dynamic link time (i.e. when execute the program) by memsetting the page to zero. @2501, you should lurk more.

Comment: @Kay: Thanks for correcting me. You are right. Found more info on wiki. Made the changes.